# how to scroll till particular position using xctest

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctest

I am trying to swipe up to a particular element in my app, if i use "swipeup" it is going to bottom of the view, which i don't want

Here is my code :

```
XCUIElement *staticText = [[[tablesQuery2 childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeCell] elementBoundByIndex:2] childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeStaticText].element;
[staticText swipeUp];
```

**Here is my app screen before using swipe up**
[image]
**Here is my app screen after using swipe up**
[image]

Comment: if your scroll contains same hieght  use tag for Views you are using do multiply views with that tag to make content offset 
else if view contains irragular height do get height of each view and in scroll and and them till spacific view and then make content size.

Comment: I dint get it @AbuUlHassan , are you saying that I have to use co-ordinates and then scroll till there ? giving an example `[[[app coordinateWithNormalizedOffset:CGVectorMake(0.0, 94.0)] coordinateWithOffset:CGVectorMake(375.0,44.0)] tap];`

Comment: no no i am saying to loop you scroll for sub views get their hieghts till you specific view not found and set scroll.contentOffset.y = calculatedheight

Answer (score 0):

If you know which element you want to select and the height of each picker item, you can make an extension of XCUIElement to select the right value.

```
/// Move up/down the picker options until the given `selectionPosition` is reached.
func changePickerSelection(pickerWheel: XCUIElement, selectionPosition: UInt) {
    // Select the new value
    var valueSelected = false
    while !valueSelected {
        // Get the picker wheel's current position
        if let pickerValue = pickerWheel.value {
            let currentPosition = UInt(getPickerState(String(pickerValue)).currentPosition)
            switch currentPosition.compared(to: selectionPosition) {
            case .GreaterThan:
                pickerWheel.selectPreviousOption()
            case .LessThan:
                pickerWheel.selectNextOption()
            case .Equal:
                valueSelected = true
            }
        }
    }
}

/// Extend XCUIElement to contain methods for moving to the next/previous value of a picker.
extension XCUIElement {
    /// Scrolls a picker wheel up by one option.
    func selectNextOption() {
        let startCoord = self.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.5))
        let endCoord = startCoord.coordinateWithOffset(CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 30.0)) // 30pts = height of picker item
        endCoord.tap()
    }

    /// Scrolls a picker wheel down by one option.
    func selectPreviousOption() {
        let startCoord = self.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.5))
        let endCoord = startCoord.coordinateWithOffset(CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -30.0))
        endCoord.tap()
    }
}

let pickerWheel = app.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 0)
changePickerSelection(pickerWheel, selectionPosition: 2)
```